# Application Suspension time in JRocket Garbage collector

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

i am new to Garbage Collector

i need to calculate suspension time of an application for different JVM using gc logs files , i done this for SUN using **-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime** which gives me this output in log file

**Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0012997 seconds**

but for remaining JVM's

1.JRocket

2.IBM

i didn't find any flag's like SUN JVM

Please explain me to get this **suspension time or stopped time of an application** using any **flag's** or any **other process to calculate** for above JVM's

Answer (score 1):

To JRockit:
1. use JFR to record, which is much better than log
2. use java -Xverbose:gcpause=debug

Comment: **Thanks James**. Plz explain me How to find suspension time and count for an application occured in a gc log file with some example, i didn't get that whether **sum of all gc pause time = suspension time of an application **or not  if yes when concurrent mark sweep occurs it wont stop app threads in that case ho can we do else how to calculate those ,In dyna trace tool they are calculating suspension time and suspension count by the output of the **-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps and -XX:+PrintGCDetails from log files** two flags for SUN .Please **explain me with some gc log file**.